# PFFile to UIImage with swift 3?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, back4app

I'm trying to use this code

```
if let userPicture = object.valueForKey("Image")! as! PFFile {
   userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
      (imageData: Data!, error: Error!) -> Void in
         if (error == nil) {
            let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
            self.ImageArray.append(image)
         }
      })
}
```

I got this error

> Cannot convert value of type '(Data!, Error!) -> Void' to expected
>   argument type 'PFDataResultBlock?'

Comment: It looks to me like the completion block you have written out doesn't match the expected `PFDataResultBlock` from the Parse framework. I haven't used Parse since they shut it down, but what do the Parse docs say? What's the expected syntax for a `PFDataResultBlock`. It seems weird to me to force unwrap `Data` and `Error`. Are you sure it's not supposed to be `(imageData: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in`?

Comment: also check the syntax for `PFDataResultBlock`. Has it been updated? It might need to use `NSData` instead of `Data` and `NSError` instead of `Error`. Just a thought. The only reason I say that is because, Parse was shut down like a year ago wasn't it?

Comment: I'm sure about Data and Error instead of NSData and NSError 
because i have use it before and I got error when I use NSError.
Parse has become Open Source , and now there is some alternative using Parse like Back4app.com

Comment: I think you just need to replace your exclamation points `!` with `?`. So say `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in .... )}`

Comment: Thank you . I solve it , for some reason in Swift 3 
`userPicture.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` become `userPicture.getDataInBackground` and `NSData` = `Data` , `NSError` = `Error`

Comment: It just sounds like the Parse SDK has been updated to work with Swift 3. They've been working to cut out any unnecessary language and make function names more succinct

Comment: You are right also `!` should be `?` I got error if I make it `!`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved my problem

Swift 3 :

```
if let userPicture = object.valueForKey("Image")! as! PFFile {
userPicture.getDataInBackground({ (imageData: Data?, error: Error?) -> Void in
let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
if image != nil {
self.imageArray.append(image!)
 }
 })
}
```